# Trying to read email files using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read email files in a folder directory but I'm getting this error:

> AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'message_from_file'

```
import os
import email

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(directory):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        f = os.path.join(dirName, fname) 
        with open(f) as email: 
            msg = email.message_from_file(f)
            print(msg['from'])
```

This is what the file looks like:

```
Message-ID: <28704291.1075859174954.JavaMail.evans@thyme>
Date: Mon, 5 Nov 2001 07:08:06 -0800 (PST)
From: hai.chen@enron.com
To: harry.arora@enron.com
Subject: vol book spreadsheets
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-From: Chen, Hai </O=ENRON/OU=NA/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=HCHEN2>
X-To: Arora, Harry </O=ENRON/OU=NA/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=Harora>
X-cc: 
X-bcc: 
X-Folder: \Harry_Arora_Jan2002\Arora, Harry\Inbox
X-Origin: Arora-H
X-FileName: harora (Non-Privileged).pst
```

Comment: what are you using to read email ??

Comment: @gommb yea I am, updated OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the variable name. Currently your `email` variable is overriding the module reference to the `email` module. Try this:

```
with open(f) as file: 
     msg = email.message_from_file(file)
     print(msg['from'])
```

Comment: Ohhh I see that makes sense, seems like it's working